# How to find the list of valid arguments for phonograph aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate, foundry-phonograph

Phonograph2 is based off ElasticSearch but has a few differences that can sometime throw the following error message:

```
errorCode: INVALID_ARGUMENT
errorName: Conjure:UnprocessableEntity
```

How to find out the set of valid properties that can be used for the phonograph2 service API?

Answer (score 0):

On your Foundry instance you should be able to find the API definition for Phonograph2 in the documentation at a relative URL like `[myFoundryInstance.com]/workspace/documentation/developer/api/phonograph2`

Comment: Thanks Logan, unfortunately parts of the documentation under `/workspace/documentation/developer/api/phonograph2/objects/com.palantir.phonograph2.api.ObjectSearchRequest` gives no further details for Aggregations, SortSpec, or HighlightRequest. For some we can match Elasticsearch 6 behavior, but for others it's unclear what subset is supported.

Comment: @Julio We don't recommend hitting phonograph directly, thus why you may not find everything in the exposed documentation. If you work at a client that has workstreams that directly query phonograph, it's better for you to reach out through internal support.

Comment: @fmsf do you mind expanding on why it's not recommended via the given APIs?

Comment: There are many reasons, one being that Phonograph has always been a private API not intended for external consumption. There are however exceptions to this rule by agreements with Palantir. Another one is that Object Storage V2 is available to address the problems with Object storage V1 (Phonograph powers Object Storage V1) Foundry is already, though slowly, transitioning to  Object Storage V2, whenever this is complete we'll likely deprecate Phonograph and ask for apps that Hit Phonograph get migrated. If you query things via OSS or Functions + OSS these migrations will be seamless.